# Sales Path deployment issue

Tags: deployment, opportunity, sales

A new stage has been added in Opportunity and a new Sales Process is been created for which the stage value available for edit is updated. A sales path is created for a record type where the new created stage is referenced and hench will deploying the sales path recieiving the following error :Cannot insert Path Assistant Step Item: Picklist value is not supported.

Comment: Have you seen the [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gWXQAY) around this?

Comment: yes i did, but did not help, additionally it is about the Managed Object